# Neovim Performing Unwanted Linting Without Configuration

Tags: javascript, vim, jshint, neovim

I have been using Neovim with vim-plug for months without issue, but after changing my project setup, Neovim appears to be invoking JSHint despite the fact that I never told it to call JSHint - in fact, *even after removing all configuration in init.vim, Neovim still does linting with JSHint*. My config previously:

```
"
" vim-plug
"

call plug#begin('~/.cache/vim-plug')

" Plugins
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }
" File Tree
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
" Executing build/syntax checking for projects
Plug 'neomake/neomake'
" JavaScript syntax
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
" Agda syntax
Plug 'derekelkins/agda-vim'
" Rust syntax
Plug 'rust-lang/rust.vim'
" Idris syntax
Plug 'idris-hackers/idris-vim'
" JSX syntax
Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'
" Reason syntax + helpers
Plug 'reasonml-editor/vim-reason-plus'
Plug 'autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim', {
    \ 'branch': 'next',
    \ 'do': 'bash install.sh',
    \ }
" Optional 'multi-entry selection UI' for LanguageClient
Plug 'junegunn/fzf'
" Color schemes
Plug 'frankier/neovim-colors-solarized-truecolor-only'

call plug#end()

"
" General Config
"

" Custom Leader
let mapleader = ","

" Syntax highlighing
syntax enable

" Indent
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

" Show cursor line and column number
set ruler
" Show line number at beginning of each line
set number

" Syntax highlighing
syntax enable

" Indent
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab

" Color scheme
set termguicolors
colorscheme solarized
set background=dark

" Color scheme
set termguicolors
colorscheme solarized
set background=dark

" Recognize .vue as .html
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.vue setfiletype html
" Prolog is not perl
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.pl setfiletype prolog
" Agda
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.agda setf agda
" Use JSX in .js files
let g:jsx_ext_required = 0
" Support flow type annotations in js
let g:javascript_plugin_flow = 1

" Use system clipboard
set clipboard=unnamedplus

" Allow use of the mouse
set mouse=a

" Resizing buffers/splits shortcuts
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>h :vertical resize -5<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>j :resize -5<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>k :resize +5<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>l :vertical resize +5<CR>

"
" deoplete.nvim
"

call deoplete#enable()

"
" Neomake
"

autocmd! BufWritePost * Neomake

let g:neomake_javascript_enabled_makers = ['eslint']

"
" Language Client
"

let g:LanguageClient_serverCommands = {
    \ 'reason': ['ocaml-language-server', '--stdio'],
    \ 'ocaml': ['ocaml-language-server', '--stdio'],
    \ }

nnoremap <silent> gd :call LanguageClient_textDocument_definition()<cr>
nnoremap <silent> gf :call LanguageClient_textDocument_formatting()<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <cr> :call LanguageClient_textDocument_hover()<cr>
```

Minimal config (still performs linting)

```
call plug#begin('~/.cache/vim-plug')
" File Tree
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
call plug#end()
```

I have also tried `PlugClean`. Does Neovim have linters enabled by default? If so, how do I disable them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting neovim with no config and no plugins - `nvim -u NONE`

If that fixes it then a plugin file is still being loaded somewhere. Vim can also load plugins that vim-plug doesn't know about. The native way of loading plugins is vim will search your `runtimepath` for any subdirectories called `plugin`, and source all scripts found in there (this is how vim-plug works, it just appends each plugin directory to the runtimepath).My guess would be you've stuck something in `~/.config/nvim/plugin/` and forgotten about it (or wherever you defined XDG)

You can check your runtimepath with `:set rtp?` or `:echo &rtp` (`rtp` is interchanable with `runtimepath`). More usefully, you can check every script that neovim has sourced with the `:scriptnames` command, which should help you pinpoint anything unexpected.

Obviously there's help on all of this:

```
:h -u
:h 'runtimepath'
:h plugin
```

Comment: Neovim was sourcing files from my global vimfiles (/usr/share/vim/vimfiles) - weird that I didn't see this issue earlier! Thanks!

Comment: Be careful there, there's a couple reasons why that worries me:

Neovim shouldn't be sourcing `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles` unless you tell it to, that's part of *vim's* runtime. The equivalent location would be `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/nvim/site` (defaults to `/usr/share/nvim/site` and `/usr/local/share/nvim/site`. Are you sure you don't have the environment Variables `$VIM` or `$VIMRUNTIME` defined, making neovim look in vim's runtime instead of it's own?  


Secondly those files in `/usr/` are generally for system configuration only, only stuff from your distro should be in there.